# extremely similar questions - Is it normal/allowed

Tags: discussion

A user has been asking the same questions repeatedly with very slight modifications in the past week.

Shouldn't they simply make adjustments to their relevant question to get a suitable answer if those supplied aren't satisfactory because they don't like any that they don't come with on their own?

It is obviously not a case of spamming but it is of overall really bad quality and appears to only serve in self-promotion and getting points.

I'm curious to get your take on this.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the bounty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Maybe it's best to ask oneself: *Is the question as it stands ever
  possibly useful to anyone else?*
- And if there is no answer yet then additionally: *How likely is 
  anyone else is ever going to post an answer?*

Otherwise, just hold back on downvoting and maybe also thinking about whether any of the flags would apply… (e.g. I think "unclear" would have applied in some of the user's posts).

Remember, don't care about the people asking questions too much, what makes the site run are answers.

Answer (score 15):

In my *opinion*, asking a new question about a similar thing (but another aspect of it) is much more preferable to modifying (adjusting) an existing question. It's extremely frustrating when someone modifies a question as it possibly totally invalidates a number of submitted answers.

It's also preferable to submit multiple questions about details rather than collecting everything in one huge (and possibly vague) question, as the individual questions may be of more use to others. Keep an eye out for XY-problems though!

I have noticed that there are a lot of questions about particular topics from particular users, and I might wish people actually *read their manuals a bit closer*, but I'll answer if I feel inclined, without actually looking at who's asking most of the time.

In the case of this particular individual, he's obviously working something out. I don't think it's a matter of farming reputation.

Having said that, I *will* be paying more attention to the panel on the right and its "Related" list of similar questions in the future, in general.

Comment: I suppose you have a good point there.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes, what Kusalananda said. Asking a new question is absolutely the right thing to do. The user in question has done nothing wrong. Also, in future, please avoid naming specific users. Ask about a behavior not necessarily a person.